# PY4J error while making graphframes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqMSz.png)
I'm facing an error when I try to create a GraphFrame in my Google Colab environment. I'm using PySpark version 3.5.0, and I suspect that there might be compatibility issues with the versions of Spark, Scala, and GraphFrame I have installed. This issue has left me stuck, and I'm looking for guidance on how to address it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)